# Post Data Through Form after Confirm Popup - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hi so I have a form..

```
 echo "<form onsubmit='return deleteRecord()' method='post'  action='delete.php'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddensimcode' value='$code'  >";
        echo "<input type='submit' id='deletesimbtn' value='Delete  Product'>";
        echo "</form>";
```

And the javascript...

```
     function deleteRecord() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?")){
            return true;
            }  else {
                return false;
                }   
    }
```

Basically its a 'Delete' button to delete a record but a popup appears to verify the users action.

My problem is the data '$code' is not being posted to delete.php?

Anybody have an idea? Thanks

Comment: where does $code comes from, do you have another hidden input in the form with the name hidden? If you give the submit button a name can you see it in the post?

Comment: @swidmann code comes from the database using a query, thats fine. I don't get what you mean by naming submit button....

Comment: <input type='submit' name='somename'

Comment: @swidmann ya but how do i see it in the post?

Comment: How did you verify that delete.php does not get the value? Most likely the problem happens there. Do a `var_export($_POST);` at the beginning of delete.php, what does it report?

Comment: @syck on delete.php i did $code = $_POST['hidden']; then echo $code. Nothing displays

Comment: Are you sure the form is submitted at all? According to the present answers, it wont even get submitted due to the JS error. Did you make sure that `$code` contains anything when you generate the form? And again, `var_export($_POST);` at the beginning of delete.php to see what you get or whether you anything at all.

Comment: @syck yes $code has a value, this is what var export gave me...array ( 'hiddensimcode' => ' ', )

Comment: and what brings `var_export($_POST);` in delete.php

Answer (score 1):

You should change the function name delete() to delete_product() like this. because delete is the predefined keyword in JS. Try with different name.

Comment: you have to change the function name in both php code and java script code. am confident that it will work.

Comment: press control and f5 to re load the page

Answer (score 0):

Look in js console and you will see:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete
```

This is because it is a reserved JS keyword, change the function name and the call to it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the "delete" function name is conflicting with the js engine - changed the js function name as follows and it works ok. ( also refined the function slightly )

```
echo "
<form onsubmit='return delete_product()' method='post'  action='target.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='$code'  >
    <input type='submit' id='deletesimbtn' value='Delete  Product'>
</form>";



function delete_product() {
    return confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete this product?" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have to say it, because others already did, an that was the solution:

> As mentioned by others, change the "delete" function name.

A small example:

```
File Structure:
public_html
    |----- index.php
    |----- delete.php
```

Example index.php

```
<?php
$code = "dummyCodeXssF";

echo "<form onsubmit='return deleteRecord()' method='post'  action='delete.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddensimcode' value='$code'  >";
echo "<input type='submit' id='deletesimbtn' value='Delete  Product'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
<script>

function deleteRecord() {
    if( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?") ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Example delete.php

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_export( $_POST );
```

OUTPUT:

```
array (
  'hiddensimcode' => 'dummyCodeXssF',
)
```